# How to disable rounding of prices on WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I've been trying to disable product price rounding on WooCommerce without success. Even if I set decimals to 2 on **WooCommerce > Settings > General > Number of decimals** it will show products that are $9.99 as $10.00

After trying to find any code snippets on my plugins and themes that may be doing that and search Stack Overflow for an answer, I gave up. Any help would be truly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. In fact, the problem was that WooCommerce was caching the old settings. To clear it I had to go to `WooCommerce > Status > Tools` and click on **Clear Transients**.

Answer (score 5):

I just had this issue. To fix it:

- Go to setting in woocommerce.
- Go to general tab.
- Change **Number of decimals** to 2.

[how to fix rounding up woocommerece currency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2PFX.png)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30046607)

Answer (score 0):

Three things to check:

1. Is your theme rounding? Some themes think they should be one-size fits all...
2. Have you checked your functions.php file for any rogue rounding snippet?
3. Are you sure the price isn't set as $9.999? That would round to $10.00.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a rounding issue with Coupons etc. by setting the Number of Decimals to 4 instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue I have had also with an ERP system, setting the decimals to 4 solved my issue.

You can then simply trim the zeroes: https://woocommerce.com/document/hide-trailing-zeros-on-prices/.

Comment: Please refrain from posting link-only answers. When the link becomes outdated, your answer does not help other people who come across the problem. Always include the essential information from the link in your answer. Thanks!