# Woocommerce rounding prices up

Tags: woocommerce

I have set prices 7,09 and in cart it shows 7,00.
How I can remove this rounding? I have custom variation price field.

My code:

```
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'          => '_number_field[' . $variation->ID . ']', 
        'label'       => __( 'Aluse hind', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Sisesta aluse hind.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'       => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_number_field', true ),
        'custom_attributes' => array(
                        'step'  => 'any',
                        'min'   => '0'
                    ) 
    )
);
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_show_variation_price',  function() { return TRUE;});
function custom_product_get_price( $price, $product ){
    if (!empty(get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_number_field', true))) {
        return get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_number_field', true);
    } else {
        return get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_price', true);
    }
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable rounding of prices on WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50917494/how-to-disable-rounding-of-prices-on-woocommerce)

Comment: No! it didnt help, tried already this.

Comment: You tried the "Clear Transients" thing?

Comment: Yes I tried this "Clear Transients"!

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/problem-with-woocommerce-rounding-2/), looks like it will always be a small change in the zecimals

Comment: If I used dot instead comma then it rounded it to 8$....

Comment: `string(4) "7,03" string(4) "7,03" string(4) "7,03"` dumped price and it works. but if I return price then it is rounding to 7,0..

Answer (score 0):

**It is not a rounding problem.** You're just passing a string as a price and the float conversion truncates the decimals.

If the value of the custom field `_number_field` uses a comma it must be converted to a numeric value (float), replacing the comma with the decimal point.

In your log file you will also find the notice: `Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered`.

Furthermore, the `woocommerce_product_variation_get_price` hook already returns the meta `_price` of the product variation so the else declaration is not necessary.

You can optimize the `custom_product_get_price` function like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_variation_get_price', 'custom_product_get_price', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_get_price( $price, $product ) {

    if ( ! empty( get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_number_field', true) ) ) {
        $new_price = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_number_field', true );
        $new_price = (float) str_replace( ',', '.', $new_price );
    }

    if ( isset($new_price) ) {
        return $new_price;
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
    
}
```

*The code has been tested and works.*